# Picture (logotype) in Vista window header

Tags: c++, c, wpf, user-interface, windows-vista

There is a nice feature in modern windows applications for vista. It is picture in the window header. For instance new skype (v4) and google chrome have it.

I was woundering what is technology behinde it? If you switch off aero style, windows still has decaration. Probably application totaly redraw window frame.

However, I didn't find any information about it. May be someone already face with this feature or tried to implement it.

Comment: chrome is open source, can't you go look at it?

Answer (score 1):

Those applications don't use native windows rendering. If you look at skype you'll notice that the min/max/close buttons don't glow like they do in normal Vista apps.

If using WPF, here's an example of creating your own window:

http://www.kirupa.com/blend_wpf/custom_wpf_windows.htm